# sample queries being run by Long Running Lambdas

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda

How do I find sample queries being run by Long Running Lambdas?

Tried submitting the lambda, went into aurora ADMIN --> Client Connections and tried to get a few queries from there.
Also, tried using cloudwatch -> log groups--> but it did not lead anywhere.

I need to find the SQL queries that run when a lambda is submitted.